# Regex to match a group and ignore everything else after a pattern for Google's re2

Tags: sql, regex, string, google-bigquery

I am trying to do the following in my Bigquery sql:

```
input: myword1 myword my 3433123 other stuff
output: myword1 myword my
input: myword 23498780000123 more stuff
output: myword
```

I want the output shown above based on the above input.
I need everything before the numbers.

I tried using `^([\s\w\s]+)(?=[^\d\r\n]+\d+[^\d\r\n]+$)` but re2 doesn't like it.
Re2 doesn't like `?=` . Hope that helps

Comment: *"but re2 doesn't like it."* is not much of a question.

Comment: You should give example of expected output, what do you want to match and not match?

Comment: What is the logic you want? It looks like that's just everything before the first digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want everything before the first digit. If so, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '\s*\d.*$', '')
```